# Regular expression to get a specific group

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have this expression: `(\D)((-?|\+?)\d+(\.\d+)?)?` This work for the most of the patterns i get. But, exists this pattern in the string that a i don't be able to get at all. I'm using Java with spring boot

This is the string that a apply the regex:

```
$1.0?8S0.0H692.8Q651.7u3.3o294.8n0t32.6s0R0.0P0.0Y114.9|136.3%1N-22.08930501E-48.05973392D692.374U0.0V0.00O0.0I6G0.20F12h0.000v0.000x1y1a24.0412e5.0690b0.00l0.0000r0.0000f0p4¨0.0@0.0c0.0d0.0º0|0|0|0=51.9988B1.0#0
```

It's is simply, get the first character that's not a digit, after get the plus or minus character, after get the number. if exists a float point, get the point with the remnant numbers. This is the common pattern. The result is something like:

- **$ - 1.0**
- **? - 8**
- **S - 0.0**
- **= - 51.9988**
- **t - 32.6**

After a put this in a HashMap.

But there is a part that i have more than one number to get, separated by pipe :

- **Y114.9|136.3**
- **º0|0|0|0**

Because of the firts rule, this is interpreted as another value.

I want to change the regex to deal with this specific rule. To get something like this:

- **Y - 114.9 | 136.3**
- **º - 0 | 0 | 0 | 0**

After this i will develop a logic to put this in an array

Thank's to anyone for the help

Comment: How do `S` and `t` qualify for your “the first character that's not a letter” and how do you get the shown result with the shown pattern? Provide a [mre] that produces this result with the given input string.

Comment: Also what is your string and why do you need a regex for it (i.e. does it already _have_ a parser for it that would make a lot more sense to use)

Comment: Sorry, i wrote wrong. The first character that's not a digit

Comment: This is the parse logic.

Comment: your regex doesn't match your description. "get the first character that's not a letter" and `\D` are very different things. Did you mean `\W` or did you mean "get the first character that's not a digit"? Because "It's is simply, get the first character that's not a letter, after get the plus or minus character, after get the number. if exists a float point, get the point with the remnant numbers." translates to `\W[+-]\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: yes, that's what I meant, character that's not a digit. I don't know how to correct the question.

Comment: You can click the [edit] link either right here, or at the bottom of your post, below the tags. And on a regex note: don't use `(-?|+?)`, there's already syntax for "one out of a possible set of characters", so just use `[+\-]`.

Comment: Perhaps something like this? `[^\d\s.=+-][-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` https://regex101.com/r/fUT6oa/1

Comment: The fourth bird, is something like that. But this part is missing: =51.9988

Comment: I removed the equals sign and it work

Comment: Post this as your answer

Comment: Maybe, you’re thinking too complicated. For your example string, `"(.)([-+\\d.|]*)"` would already do the job. Yes, that would pick up invalid groups for invalid input, but what would you do with invalid input anyway? I’d rather want detect it instead of extracting some happen-to-be-valid parts and ignoring the rest.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, note that `(-?|\+?)` is equivalent to `[+-]?` (except for the capture in the former, which may be an empty string). `+` in the former must be escaped and `-` in the latter need not be escaped if it is the first or last character in the character class. I'm sure you know all this--just wanted you to know your comment was a little sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `\D` (which would match any character except a digit) to a more specific negated character class `[^\d\s.+-]` excluding more characters.

For the part with the repeated pipe `|` char and the digits, you can use optionally repeating non capture group.

If you don't want to get the individual parts, you can omit the capture groups at all and just get the full match.

You could use:

```
[^\d\s.+-][-+]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*
```

The pattern in parts match:

- `[^\d\s.+-]` Match a single character other than a digit, whitspace char or one of  `.` `+` `-`
- `[-+]?` Match an optional `-` or `+`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` Optionally repeat `|` followed by 1+ digits with an optional decimal part

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNTdui/1)

Answer (score 0):

The \D non-digits should exclude space as well. Thus list digits and whitespaces to exclude. You should check also if there is space(s) between the elements. Your regex to capture the 'data' should be as follows

```
([^0-9\s]\s*?[-+]\s*?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)
```

Explanation by elements

```
 ([^0-9\s]              non-digit and not space
    \s*?                possibly space
    [-+]                -/+
    \s*?                possibly space
    [0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)    the number
```

To get multiple numbers (with pipes)

```
([^0-9\s]\s*?[-+]\s*?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?(?:\s*?\|\s*?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)*?)
```

Explanation by elements

```
 ([^0-9\s]                    non-digit and not space
 \s*?                         possibly space
 [-+]                         - / +
 \s*?                         possibly space
 [0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?         a number 
 (?:\s*?\|\s*?[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?)*?)  possibly multiple of '|number'
```